# Best practices for importing matrix data

Tags: matrix, import, datagrab

I have some pages that display various information about specific college majors, including a table for the names of employers who hire the major and a table for job titles of those majors (http://career.uga.edu/classof2016/major_summary16/accounting_-_bachelors16). At the moment, the employer names are not connected with the job titles.

For each record/specific major/page, I need to display a new table with an employer name in the first column and all of the associated job titles in the second column.

I have started by adding a new matrix field to the existing data channel. I can use this to manually enter and display data the way I need to, but I have a significant number of records to import and I don't know if that will work with the Matrix field.

So here's my question: is there a preferred and/or simpler, native way to format a table that will display what I need?

Would it be better to create a new channel for the major, employer name, job title fields, and then pull that into the template that displays the existing data for each major using a relationship field?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix (or native grid field) can become unwiedly with a lot of records so I'd go down the relationship route. Create a new channel for the data, you can then use relationship field(s) to associate them with any other channel you want.